# Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar to match attributes

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin

My react native app is giving me the following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-s
tdlib:1.4.10) to match attributes {artifactType=android-java-res, org.gradle.cat
egory=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gr
adle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin
-stdlib:1.4.10)
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetb
rains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.4.10/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/
kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.4.10/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar'.
               > No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)
```

I don't know why it is giving me the error because i just build this app and am running it for the first time. Can Anyone please help me.